# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'Jcrop', on IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jcrop

Some times this problem appear on IE 10, 9 etc. how I can fix that. Because is not fanny, every script is included one by one, nothing is not in plus, jCrop is running on Document ready.

How I can solve this prorblem ?

```
//some code
 var this_ = this;
 this.editedSingatureImage = document.createElement("img");
 document.body.appendChild( this.editedSingatureImage);

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jcrop_api = jQuery.Jcrop(jQuery(this_.editedSingatureImage), {
        bgColor: '#eee',
        setSelect: defaultCoordentes,
        onSelect: function (c) {
            //my code
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Show us some code. Error means there is a problem.

Comment: you can see example, nothing is not so complicates

Comment: "every script is included one by one, nothing is not in" Show us the `<script>` tags.

Comment: I include script one by one, but some times when we do refresh, we receive this problem of missing Jcrop class. this prroblem appear only on IE